# Unity XR and Photon pun

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, photon-pun

I have successfully created an XR project using Photon PUN networking, and the multiplayer functionality works well on Oculus. Now, I need to build the same project for different devices, such as Oculus and WebGL. What are the steps I should follow?

How can I solve this problem, and what steps should I follow?